# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (related to URL pulled from XML feed)

Tags: swift, webview

I guess this is a pretty common error but is caused by different reasons. That's why I would appreciate your help on mine a lot.

I am trying to send URL from the XML feed to the viewcontroller which includes a webview.

Here is my segue code in tableview controller which includes article titles:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "openPage" {

        var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let wvc: WebViewController = segue.destinationViewController as WebViewController
        var selectedURL: String = feeds[indexPath.row].objectForKey("link") as String
        selectedURL = selectedURL.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
        selectedURL = selectedURL.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "")
        wvc.selectedLink = selectedURL
        println(selectedURL)
    }
}
```

`openPage` connects my tableview to webview viewcontroller. I print selectedURL and it works perfectly. Here is the code for ViewController including webview:

```
var selectedLink = ""

@IBOutlet var myWebView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myWebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: selectedLink)!))
}
```

This returns the error. I dont see any problem and the tutorial I used has the exact code and runs properly without any issue. The URL structure is also perfectly fine as I tried the printed version of the selectedURL in my webview directly, it worked. I guess the problem is with segue connection but couldnt figure out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the passing of your link to your webview-controller work? Can you check if it is passed correctly?

Comment: You must identify which optional is failing to get unwrapped successfully. Which one is `nil`? Test each and every optional value and find out which one is failing. A likely candidate is the `NSURL` (e.g. perhaps you neglected to include the "http://" at the start; we can't tell without seeing the URL). It could be the `UIWebView` if you failed to hook up your `IBOutlet`. We have no way of telling.

Comment: @ChristianWoerz: yes it works. i printed selectedLink value successfully, which means i have it in my webview-controller, before the webview tried to load it.

Comment: @Rob: thanks for the guidance, the selectedLink value is `http://www.marketoloji.com/2015/01/06/ucuncu-dalga-kahve/` and it looks perfectly fine in webviewcontroller just before the webview load. i also checked the webview `IBOutlet`, which is connected properly to my webviewcontroller. any other pieces you suggest me to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the NSURL is really a valid URL. Browsers like Chrome or Safari do accept many URLs which aren't valid really.

So you should check your URL if it's valid. Otherwise it will return `nil` and you have to check your URL:

```
let unwrappedUrl: NSURL? = NSURL(string: selectedLink!)
```

If this returns nil you could also try to escape your string:

```
selectedLink = selectedLink.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

Comment: i used `let unwrappedUrl: NSURL? = NSURL(string: selectedLink)` , ran it with `if` and turned out `nil` however, when i use the exact same value of `selectedLink`, which is `http://www.marketoloji.com/2015/01/06/ucuncu-dalga-kahve/` in the webview loadrequest, it works perfectly fine. so the problem is with `selectedLink`. what do you think might be wrong with selectedLink variable?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Try to escape your string. I've had also the same issue with my app. Had the exact same problem. But suddenly it worked. It's kinda buggy I think. But escaping should work.

Comment: this time, i had no error but cant see the page :( No page found error on the landing page..so weird!

Comment: i had to change my permalink structure to default to make it work :)